# WCF service timing out before the specified timeout value passes

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which is called by my console application. The console app is setup as a scheduled task in windows that runs once a day. The console app calls the WCF service operation and the operation takes long and the error received at the console app is that

```
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 11:59:59.9050000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout
```

I have set up all 4 timeouts at 12 hours but still it timesout within the first minute of executing and I receive the above error about timeout which says its been waiting for 11:59:59.9050000 but I know it didnt wait for more than 1 minute. Does anyone know why?

Here are my binding properties in my `app.config`:

```xml
    <binding name="HoldbackEndpoint" closeTimeout="12:00:00" openTimeout="12:00:00"
      receiveTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="12:00:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="999" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: I think something is overwriting your timeout value to a shorter one, causing a write-write error.

Comment: From my experience, this could mean there is an error processing the request on the Server.  Try turning on WCF tracing and see what that gives you. [here is some info on tracing][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is strange because the message doesn't fit the timeout. Looks like a bug. Use Fiddler to inspect request and response. What do you find?

Comment: the service is hosted in IIS or else?

Comment: Yes the service is hosted in IIS on a different machine than my local machine. I run the console app from my machine & the service is within the same network on a different machine.

I also hosted the service on my local machine on ASP.NET development server from visual studio for debugging & I updated the console app config file to point to this local machine hosted service & it does not timeout. It is ran smoothly & completed without errors. But this is not how I want it eventually. I want to host the service on the server. On the IIS server event viewer I dont see any errors logged.